# Is it possible to use this library with android 2.3?

Tags: android, version

I am very interested in this framework: https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar

Unfortunately in the manifest.xml it says

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Can I still use this with Android 2.3? I'm curious, because I do know there is a android v4 support library out there and I was wondering if that would help?

Comment: Why don't you ask the author directly?

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="4".... What does this say to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, API Level 9 is Android 2.3 - 2.3.2, also known as Gingerbread.

The **android:minSdkVersion** is 4, also known as Donut (1.6). So yes you can use it.

For all Codenames, Tags, and Build Numbers, check [**here**](http://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html)

Answer (score 0):

It does say minSDKverion 4, which is Donut (1.6), so why shouldn't you?

You can check the versions that correspond to the sdk numbers and their usage stats from [**here**](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The minimum is 4 so as long as the SDK is above version 4 you can use it. So yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The `android:minSdkVersion="4"` says it's compatible with any version above API level 4 so you can use it since android 2.3 is API level 9